# Converting a map in Cartesian projection (with spherical coordinate) to healix projection

Tags: healpy

I have a map with spherical coordinate system in Cartesian projection. The header file reads CTYPE1 = 'GLON-CAR' and CTYPE2 = 'GLAT-CAR'.  I want to convert this map to healpix projection. I understand that I need to convert the  map in spherical coordinate to healpix pixels using tool "ang2pix". But I am not able to understand to how to fill the pixel with the values that are available in cartesian projection.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to not re-invent the wheel, and to benefit from the efforts of others that came before you. Check out the [reproject](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package and in particular [reproject_to_healpix()](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/reproject.reproject_to_healpix.html#reproject.reproject_to_healpix), it will do everything you need.